# Incorrect pixel value from data cursor on Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom

When I open a Dicom image on Matlab (R2014b) and place the data cursor on a specific set of coordinates, I obtain an "index" (or pixel value) that does not match the same set of coordinates on the image's matrix (T).

```
>> figure, imshow(T);
```

See below on attached image.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: And if you check the pixel at `[557 89]`? The coordinate system for images is different than generic matrices.

Comment: you're so right, the coordinate system on the matrix is `column = x` and `row = y`, which for some reason I feel is "reversed". When I do `T(557,89)` it returns `5380` as you suggested. Please feel free to add this as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using images, the data cursor tool with MATLAB's `figure` and its various ilk assume that `X` and `Y` are the **column** (horizontal) and **row** (vertical) coordinates respectively.  In the variable inspector (the left part of your figure), these are reversed.

Be careful when using the data cursor on images.  See this post by MathWorks on more details regarding interactive display of data: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html